# Is it possible to open a new window and embed iframe in to this?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, popup, window.open

I need to open a new window and  I want to embed a video in an iframe and show it in this window. As normal pop-up window syntax is:

```
window.open(URL,name,specs,replace)
```

How will I pass the iframe code instead of URL so that the iframe is embedded in the new window?  Please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You don't pass the iframe code to `window.open`, you get a handle on the window you are opening and write the iframe to that window.

```
var win = window.open();
win.document.write('<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/mTWfqi3-3qU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>')
```

Comment: I want same functionality with PDF doc I just replace the src with pdf content but not working

Comment: @AbdulHameed you want the pdf in an iframe inside the pop up window? If so, it should work the same as the YouTube link in the iframe, I suggest checking that the path to the pdf file is correct

Comment: var string = doc.output('datauristring');
var iframe = "<iframe width='100%' height='100%' src='" + string + "'></iframe>"
        var x = window.open();
        x.document.open();
        x.document.write(iframe);
        x.document.close();  //Use this @AbdulHameed

Comment: window.open() currently returns null on Chrome so your provided solution is obselete

Comment: @Necroqubus not sure which version of Chrome you are running, but it works fine on the current version - Version 70.0.3538.110 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Would anyone know if with this technique i can further write into the iframe?