# Embedding window within a window

Tags: javascript, html, https, embed

My company uses HTTPS and I'm trying to embed videos that are HTTP, which doesn't work on our servers. My thoughts for a way around it is to create and embed a new window inside of the main one and then embed the video using something similar to [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20235958/1701804).

Is it possible to embed a window inside of another window? How? I'm using regular JS and html by the way, so if there's a library that will help me do this easily or another suggestion (because I usually find the hardest solutions for things), that would be appreciated!

Comment: iframe? Even so though, if there's a security policy that blocks http content, you might not be able to get around it or force it onto https

Answer (score -1):

The best option is to find a HTTPS url for the videos. Many video sharing sites can use either. You can't really fool the browser into loading http content, as this would defeat the whole purpose of the security restriction.